# MySQL Trigger doesn't update table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I created the following trigger in a MySQL database. It's for a star rating system. Whenever a row is added to the ratings table, it's supposed to add this to the ratings_totals table.

```
DELIMITER$$

create trigger update_vote_after_insert_trig before insert 
on ratings
for each row begin 
if bookID = new.bookID then
update ratings_totals set 
total_votes = total_votes + 1,
total_rating = total_rating + new.rating,
overall_rating = total_rating / total_votes;
where 
bookID = new.bookID;
ELSE
insert into ratings_totals set bookID = new.bookID, total_votes =  total_votes, total_rating =  total_rating, overall_rating = overall_rating;
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is that the ratings_totals table is incorrectly updated. It contains four rows: bookID, total_votes, total_rating and overall_rating. Only the bookID table is updated; the rest remain at 0.

My goal is to INSERT the row the first time, and update it after that. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Why are you doing insert and then update? Why don't you insert immediately?

Comment: Because after the first insert I just want to update the same rows (ie. 1 row for each item being rated). I don't want to insert a new row every time for the same item; that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I've taken out the insert line now, but that makes no difference. The trigger still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert at the first time and just update after the first time you can try to use "IF" statement.
if(this is the first time)
///your code
else
// your code

you can use "select" to find out if you inserted this row before and this will be your "IF"

Comment: Alright, I've made some changes to the code...but now I keep getting a MySQL error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER$$

create trigger update_vote_after_insert_trig before insert
on rati' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't the "new" be "old"? Like:

```
DELIMITER $$  

create trigger update_vote_after_insert after insert 
on ratings
for each row begin
  update ratings_totals set 
    total_votes = total_votes + 1,
    total_rating = total_rating + old.rating,
    overall_rating = total_rating / total_votes  
  where 
    bookID = old.bookID;

end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No, because I'm adding the newly inserted rating to the total rating.

Comment: Well the problem should be something on the new/old I think as you say  that only total_rating and overall are now updated... Please take a look at this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html and the first user comment on it. Maybe it will help

Comment: No, only bookID is updated. Nothing else is. But thanks, I'll take a look.